# Force text to fit cell when using WriteHTMLCell in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I've spent over an hour researching this and I can't seem to find the answer.

I am using writeHTMLCell in TCPDF .  I need some text to fit within a certain area when using writeHTMLCell.

I've seen an example [here (php)](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_004.phps)  and [here (pdf)](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_004.pdf)

of doing text stretch and scale, etc when using Cell, but I want to stretch or scale the text to "fit" the area when using writeHTMLCell  instead of  "Cell".

Is this possible ?  Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I managed to achieve this was to scrap using the `writeHTMLCell` method and used `Cell`. It's a pain having to convert your HTML into using the `Cell` method, especially if you want to use CSS styling. I spent many an hour trying to accomplish the same stretching ability of Cell with writeHTMLCell, and in the end I just converted all of the positioning, styling, etc. to the `Cell` element.

One thing that helped a lot was finding out that the positioning of `Cell` and `writeHTMLCell` is quite different. The `writeHTMLCell` method specifies an x and y coordinate to be passed in a long with the text content. The `Cell` element actually uses an entirely different positioning system in that you have to define **before hand** where you want the "cursor" to be moved to. For example,

```
$pdf->SetXY(50, 50);
```

Will move the cursor to 50, 50 coordinate, and then by writing a `Cell` it will position this element according to that coordinate. [Official Doc on Set XY](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00ec13928f57b17c21040acc881fe482)

So I could basically just take out the first two parameters of `writeHTMLCell` and move them into `SetXY`. Once you have the `Cell` element formatted and positioned like you want it. The Stretching / Scaling capability is excellent in TCPDF. I wish there was a better solution for this problem, but I decided that to use Cell would be a better option.

Hope this helps! ;)